# How to create a redirect url from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A user has a listing. For example, user 1 has listing 2. The current URL will look something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/listings/2
```

I want to let users customize their own backlink for their listings like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/uniquelistingname
```

Ideally, I would like to have the listing URL stay like the unique one, but a redirect will do.

I found the friendly URL gem, but I'm not sure if it fully fits my needs. It seems to allow the URL to be a param as opposed to creating a fully customized one, which needs to be unique. What suggestions do you have on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create separate model for it e.g named `UserListingLink` that looks like:

```
class UserListingLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :listing

  validates :link, uniqueness: true
end
```

and just allow users edit it. Then you can redirect your users in routes (put it at the very bottom so other routes like localhost:3000/posts keep working):

**routes.rb:**

```
get '/:user_link', to: 'user_listings#show'
```

and just redirect or show whatever you want in that controller:

```
class UserListingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    listing = UserListingLink.find_by(link: params[:user_link]).listing
    redirect_to listings_path(listing)
  end
end
```

Comment: So, with this... I would need to create a separate page for the user to create a redirect for the listing? how would the form for this look and would i need to be nesting routes?

Comment: Yes, if you want it to be editable by users. It can be just default Rails form without any route nesting, it all depends on your use-case.

Comment: forgive me as i am fairly new to rails but is this what i should be donig... creating controller and models, then adding "user_link" to listings schema? and then i can simply use the listing form to create the link?